# What is a good free IDE that supports ASP highlighting and ZenCoding?

Tags: ide, asp-classic, emmet

I'm a big fan of Eclipse. It supports ZenCoding, no problem. But there is only one plugin that supports ASP highlighting, and it does a really cruddy job of finding matching pairs, which is a pretty basic function. So, are there any other good free (or cheap) IDEs that have a ZenCoding plugin *and* work well with ASP? (Dark themes and sexy UI are a plus!)

Comment: I've been trying to get my head around adding language support to NetBeans, it's not that easy, but should more time become available I'll make it.

Comment: Sounds cool. I'd definitely be interested to try that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Built in ASP support, ZenCoding plugin, matching pairs plugin, matching brackets plugin, dark theme by default, sexy UI.

Answer (score 1):

Good free IDE with ASP support ? Tough question... try [RjTextEd](http://www.rj-texted.se/), it how has built-in ZenCoding support, but its nowhere close to NetBeans or VisualStudio..